# Mongoose - Divide subdocuments using discriminators

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

If I have a model `Attachment`, which can be divided into 4 types: `Link`, `YoutubeVideo`, `GoogleDriveFile`, and `GoogleDriveFolder`, how can I use Mongoose to discriminate `Attachment` into these types, and allow them to be subdocuments in another schema; `Post`?

I've created the base `Attachment` model, and divided it into separate models using discriminators:

```
var AttachmentSchema = new Schema({
    id:     {type: String, required: true},
    title:  {type: String, required: true}
});

var Attachment = mongoose.model('Material', AttachmentSchema);

module.exports = {
    DriveFile:      Attachment.discriminator('GoogleDriveFile', new mongoose.Schema()),
    DriveFolder:    Attachment.discriminator('GoogleDriveFolder', new mongoose.Schema()),
    Link:           Attachment.discriminator('Link', new mongoose.Schema()),
    YoutubeVideo:   Attachment.discriminator('YoutubeVideo', new mongoose.Schema())
};
```

Now, in the `Post` schema, there should be an array of attachments, with varying types:

```
var Attachment = require('./attachment');

var PostSchema = new Schema(
    text:{type: String},
    attachments: [Material] // Could be Material.Link, Material.YoutubeVideo, etc
});
```

When I do this, I get an error saying "Undefined type `Model` at `GoogleDriveFile`. Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays."

I don't know what this error means, and I can't find any docs explaining how to do this. Help?

Comment: May be helpful: http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.8-embedded-discriminators.html

Answer (score 7):

Try doing the following:

```
    var AttachmentSchema = new Schema({
    id:     {type: String, required: true},
    title:  {type: String, required: true}
    });

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String },
    attachments: [ AttachmentSchema ] // Could be Material.Link, Material.YoutubeVideo, etc
});

var attachmentArray = PostSchema.path('attachments');

    module.exports = {
    Post: mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema),
    DriveFile:      attachmentArray.discriminator('GoogleDriveFile', new mongoose.Schema({})),
    DriveFolder:    attachmentArray.discriminator('GoogleDriveFolder', new mongoose.Schema({})),
    Link:           attachmentArray.discriminator('Link', new mongoose.Schema({})),
    YoutubeVideo:   attachmentArray.discriminator('YoutubeVideo', new mongoose.Schema({}))
};
```

The key is to NOT use a mongoose Model use the schema.path of the parent document schema as the base for your discriminators.

search for the term **docArray** on this link: [Mongoose Discriminator documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

Comment: Thanks sir, you saved the day.

Comment: Hey there. I'm using Typescript and Mongoose and discriminator method seems like doesn't exist on Schema type. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, only exist inside Subdocument (mongoose.Schema.Types.Subdocument)

Answer (score 0):

For others who are using **NestJS** and `nestjs/mongoose`, taking [Scott Gnile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303487/6608142) as reference, you can do it like this:

#### Main schema

```js
@Schema()
export class MainClass {
  // some properties here

  @Prop({ type: SubClass })
  sub: SubClass;
}
export const MainClassSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(MainClass);
```

#### Sub schema

```js
@Schema({ _id: false, discriminatorKey: 'kind', autoCreate: false })
export class SubClass {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: String, enum: Foo })
  kind: string;

  // Timestamp as an example for shared properties
  @Prop({ default: Date.now })
  timestamp: Date;
}


@Schema({ _id: false })
export class SubClassBar {
  kind = Foo.Bar; // Set the discriminator to the correct value

  // Add further props
}
export const SubClassBarSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SubClassBar);
```

#### Inside the module

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    { name: MainClass.name, schema: MainClassSchema },
    {
      name: SubClass.name,
      schema: MainClassSchema.path('sub').schema, // notice the .schema
      discriminators: [
        { name: Foo.Bar, schema: SubClassBarSchema },
        // add further kinds here
      ]
    }
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```